# Change form input value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the input field value dynamically when the user pick the options from my dropdown menu. I have tried this code but have no luck. I was wondering if someone here can help me out! Thanks a lot.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="job_number"]').change (function () {

    $('input[name="project"]').val()="Good Fish";

});
});

<form action='project_manager' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='project'>show Good Fish when user picks an option</input>
<select name='job_number'>
<option value='1'>job1</option>
<option value='2'>job2</option>
<option value='3'>job3</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

try :

```
$('input[name="project"]').val("Good Fish");
```

instead of:

```
$('input[name="project"]').val()="Good Fish";
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only 1 form on the page with an input named 'project'. That is true 99% of the time, just good to be aware of it.

Answer (score 17):

The code below should work. I modified the `<input>` in the html to be formatted correctly as well as changed `$('input[name="project"]').val()="Good Fish";` to `$('input[name="project"]').val("Good Fish");`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="job_number"]').change(function() {

        $('input[name="project"]').val("Good Fish");

    });
});

<form action='project_manager' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='project' value='show Good Fish when user picks an option' />
    <select name='job_number'>
        <option value='1'>job1</option>
        <option value='2'>job2</option>
        <option value='3'>job3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Keith. I wanted to give you green since you also corrected my html, but I already promised aletzo. +1 thought.