# How to change hidden input field value after form submission in php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, field, hidden

I have a form like this :

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="un" value="'.$ruser.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ups" value="'.$rpass.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="fldr" value="'.$cust_fldr.'">';
echo '<input type="text" name="user" value="'.$reg_name.'">';
echo '<input type="text" name="rname" value="'.$rname.'" >';
echo '<input type="submit" name="reg" id="simple-post" value="order" />';
```

When I click submit button, everything gets posted nicely with ajax exept hidden fields because they are empty at the moment of submission. I should give them values after form submission based on values given on form, before ajax post. How can I do it with php ?

I have googled around but I have not found solution, then I just simply tried this :

```
$_POST['un'] = $ruser;
$_POST['ups'] = $pass_reg;
$_POST['fldr'] = $cust_fldr;
```

Then ajax post

```
ajaxSend($url, $data);
```

It didn't work either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: u can use jquery for this. $('#id_of_element').val("the_value");

Comment: Rafael Care to give me an example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change form input value with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576485/change-form-input-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

First create a function for your submit button.
The function will process your data and manipulate the values of your inputs.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="un" name="un" value="'.$ruser.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="ups" name="ups" value="'.$rpass.'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="fldr" value="'.$cust_fldr.'">';
echo '<input type="text" name="user" value="'.$reg_name.'">';
echo '<input type="text" name="rname" value="'.$rname.'" >';
echo '<input type="submit" onclick='my_function();return false;' name="reg" id="simple-post" value="order" />';

<script>
function my_function(){
    $('#un').val("THE VALUE");
    $('#ups').val("THE SEC VALUE");
     var url_link = "ajax.php?action=whatever";
     $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
         url: url_link,   
         async: false,
         cache: false,
         success : function(text){
             $('#un').val("CHANGE AGAIN THE VALUE");
         }
     });
}
</script>
```

This is a small example of what you should use.