# Generating a secret code in the input field after clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

This code does not work and I do not know why I'm learning JavaScripta but I'm doing it for the first time I was also looking for a solution on the internet but I found a similar code generation and what would work

HTML, JavaScript, JQuery

```
function gencode(length) {
    var result           = "";
    var characters       = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var letters          = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var numbers          = "0123456789"
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
};

$('#btn-generate').click(function(){
    $('#secret-code').val = gencode(8);
});


<div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-holder">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <legend>'.$lang['register']['form']['secret-code']['header'].'</legend>
                                            <input type="text" id="secret-code" name="secret-code" placeholder="'.$lang['register']['form']['example']['secret-code'].'" class="required">
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-holder">
                                        <div class="center">
                                            <a class="btn tooltip tt50 generate" id="btn-generate">
                                                <span class="gencode">
                                                    <em>'.$lang['register']['form']['secret-code']['button'].'</em><i id="icon-gencode" class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: `$('#secret-code').val( gencode(8) )`

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: Please check my answer below to see a demo

Comment: You could also write your personal research and the exact point that you suspect that you are triggering the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change form input value with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576485/change-form-input-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) is a method, so to update the value, you can execute the method as:

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
function gencode(length) {
  var result = "";
  var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  var charactersLength = characters.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
  }
  return result;
};

$('#btn-generate').click(function() {
  $('#secret-code').val(gencode(8));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-holder">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Legend</legend>
      <input type="text" id="secret-code" name="secret-code" placeholder="" class="required">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="form-holder">
    <div class="center">
      <a class="btn tooltip tt50 generate" id="btn-generate">
        <span class="gencode">
            Generate
            <i id="icon-gencode" class="fa fa-code fa-2x"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the generated code still does not work

Comment: It works on the demo. Please click on `Run code snippet` to test @DJKondzio

Comment: look on my html code. for me, the <a> tag should be used to generate the code

Comment: It is working. Please check.

Comment: Now I do not know it myself, I do exactly the same, and it does not work for me to generate it

Comment: Any error on `console`?

Comment: Clear the cache maybe @DJKondzio

Comment: look on my site step 2 http://panel.xfiverecords.pl/register

Comment: as I have this script js in a separate file it does not work and so works. And one more thing how to make it random and numbers and letters only so that these numbers and letters are in separate variables

Answer (score 0):

To set value in jquery you should use **val** as function

```
$('#secret-code').val(gencode(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#secret-code').val(gencode(8));
```

It simply sets the value of every matched element. You can read all the explanation from the link below:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you offer a few words of explanation of how this works and why it's a good solution to the question?

Comment: It simply sets the value of every matched element. You can read all the explanation from the link I provided. If you have any specific questions then let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Can you put this information in the post? A strong answer usually has some (in this case, likely brief) explanation of how it works to help guide future visitors (and stops you from getting flagged by the SO robot populating the low-quality post review queues).